# locust cannot get full csv output with custom load shape

Tags: python, api, csv, load-testing, locust

In my locust load test I want to track and plot the number of users and number of requests over time. I am using locust 2.5.1.

This works fine when using the `--csv` and `csv-full-history` arguments together with time limit, user count and spawn rate passed to locust. However, when I use a custom load shape class, I only get two lines in my csv output.

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, between
from locust import LoadTestShape

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(5, 9)

    @task(1)
    def index_page(self):
    self.client.get("/")

class MyCustomShape(LoadTestShape):
    time_limit = 60
    spawn_rate = 20

    def tick(self):
    run_time = self.get_run_time()

    if run_time < self.time_limit:
            # User count rounded to nearest hundred.                                                                                                                                                        
            user_count = round(run_time, -2)
            return (user_count, self.spawn_rate)

    return None
```

I run with `locust --headless -f test-locustfile.py -H https://www.google.com  --csv iii --csv-full-history`

and then in `iii_stats_history.csv` I have only two lines:

```
Timestamp,User Count,Type,Name,Requests/s,Failures/s,50%,66%,75%,80%,90%,95%,98%,99%,99.9%,99.99%,100%,Total Request Count,Total Failure Count,Total Median Response Time,Total Average Response Time,Total Min Response Time,Total Max Response Time,Total Average Content Size
1641340173,0,GET,/,12.000000,0.000000,180,210,230,240,250,270,280,290,290,290,290,159,0,200.0,176.07068630673413,63.06202709674835,299.4416542351246,13116.591194968554
1641340173,0,,Aggregated,12.000000,0.000000,180,210,230,240,250,270,280,290,290,290,290,159,0,200.0,176.07068630673413,63.06202709674835,299.4416542351246,13116.591194968554
```

Why don't I get the data for every second as I get when I run it without a custom load shape class?

Comment: Sounds like a proper bug. You can file it on github.

Comment: Will do! I checked and the last locust version  I do not have this problem is 1.1.6.